# Why this class starts the intent twice?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have my SplashScreen activity with AsyncTask to check for files if exist. If they exist starts MainActivity class else starts the Downloader class.

The problem is when splashscreen is done, it runs the MainActivity intent twice or the Downloader intent twice. I am using android version GINGERBREAD

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

// base path of application
private final String basePath =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("MyApp").getAbsolutePath() +
                            "/files";
// files to check
private final String[] filenames = {
    "file1.txt",
    "file2.txt",
};

private boolean isOK = false;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    Thread background = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                // Thread will sleep for 5 seconds
                sleep(5 * 1000);

                // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
                // If is ok to start
                if (isOK) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                // Else download required files
                else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DownloadScreen.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                //Remove activity
                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    // check if all required files exists
    new CheckFiles().execute(filenames);

    // start thread
    background.start();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}

private class CheckFiles extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... filenames) {

        for (String filename : filenames) {
            File file = new File(basePath + filename);

            if (file.exists())
                continue;
            else return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        isOK = result;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because when you `finish()` your SplashScreen activity, it gets back to your `MainActivity` by recreating it, so this means that it will call `onCreate()` again and if you haven't stopped your prior `Thread`, it will start another one so it will be starting two intents for the same thing.

**---- EDIT ----**

To check whether the `Thread` is running, I suggest defining a `boolean` variable class-wide to control it. Set it to `false`, and once you're inside, set it to `true`.

Then, prior to call `.start()` on your `Thread`, check if the variable is `false`. If so,
call it, else, don't do it as it will start another instance and will be duplicated.

```
// start thread
if (!isAlreadyStarted)
  background.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks really strange and bad. You have a background `Thread` to check the values after sleeping for, what looks to be, an arbitrary amount of time. You can remove the `Thread` and put that code in a function. Then you can call this function when the task ends in `onPostExecute()`. Something like

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    goToActivity(result);
}

private void goToActivity(boolean ok)
{
    isOK = ok;
    Intent i;
    if (isOK) {
       i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    }
    // Else download required files
    else {
      i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DownloadScreen.class);
    }
    startActivity(i);
    //Remove activity
    finish();
}
```

Comment: i added the thread sleep there because i want the splash screen to display for about 5 seconds while doing the checks

Comment: Yes, but if you do it this way it will display the splash screen until the task finishes. There's no pertinent reason for the 5 seconds, right? You just want it to display until your task finishes and you get the result.